# Find and truncate a link from a text in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate

I'm looking for a way to truncate links displayed in my text.

```
Ie: <p><I want to share a link : http://www.itabc.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Tools-for-Ruby-on-Rails-logo.jpg it rocks!</p>

Into : <p>I want to share a link : http://www.itabc.org/wp-con... it rocks!</p>
```

I want obviously to keep my href working.

Do you have any advice for me? I guess I need to create an helper.

EDIT:

The text ins't static in my views, I want to manage content posted by users in messages, so I have to find a way to truncate links automaticaly

thx

Comment: Rails has a truncate helper method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) helper:

```
= link_to truncate(text, length: 20), path
```

You can specify the number of characters and the omission (...), for example.

**Edit**

You need to combine what is suggested on [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810541/automatically-link-urls-and-images-within-html-string) and the `truncate` method.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some guidance. I hope it's helpful.